# Cant access Windows Server via NetBIOS but FQDN works

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, filesystems, network-share, windows-10

2 Windows 10 machines. Machine1 can access \\Server1 via NetBIOS. Machine2 can not. However Machine2 can access \\Server2 via NetBIOS and Machine1 can not. If you use the FQDN it works without issue for both. 
Machine1 and Machine2 can ping both Servers via NetBIOS names without issue.

When  Machine1 tries to access \\Server2 a credentials box appears. Typing in correct credentials does not do anything. It simply shows the credential box again as seen via this url. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iTkm.png (My rep is not high enough to embed images)

Both machines have listed the same LogonServer which happens to be Server2. Both Machines use DHCP, both Servers use static IPs and all 4 devices are in the same subnet. Both servers are 2008 and are DCs.

This only happens with Windows 10. We have hundreds of Windows 7 machines that work without issue using the same user accounts.

The most annoying thing however is it is not constant. Machine1 will randomly after no changes have no issues using NetBIOS to access Server2. But will then also stop for no reason later.

We are in the process of building a Win10 SOE however this obviously is holding that back.

Comment: Can you try to run a tcpview or wireshark to help? I suspect you get a bad netbios answer.

Comment: \\Server1FQDN - Working https://i.imgur.com/rQZi04g.png

Comment: \\Server1 - Fails https://i.imgur.com/FVdP2pq.png

Comment: You can see that in the fail it cycles through Prot Request and Response without moving on. What can I look for in the response of the failed or working one to try and figure out where it is breaking?

Answer (score 1):

NetBios is a seriously legacy protocol and should not be used anywhere that has DNS implemented; everything should be using FQDN. Microsoft has been deprecating NetBT in Windows 10 / Server 2016 ever so slowly and eventually it will be outright removed.

To address your symptoms, you can append custom DNS suffixes in your IP properties for your NIC. Add each of your DNS names in the list and it will automatically append them to the server name and attempt DNS resolution. For logins, you can switch to using a UPN which looks like an email address.

Comment: Looks to be caused by how network drives map in windows 10. I had multiple network drives all mapping to \\domain\####. For some reason in Win10 vs Win7 that causes issues. Removing the network drives eliminated the problem. Does not solve my issues, but I at least know the cause....

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be caused by how network drives map in windows 10. I had multiple network drives all mapping to \domain####. For some reason in Win10 vs Win7 that causes issues. Removing the network drives eliminated the problem. Does not solve my issues, but I at least know the cause.... Will close this out as this has now become a question around network drives.